# Route mapping doesn't fine controller action method, when using areas. Err: The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've tried searching SO and read several answers, but I just can't get this route mapping working. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple.

I want to pass an optional 'tab' string through the url so I can pre-select a tab on the rendered page.  Desired URL example: `http://localhost/Manufacture/Job/View/1234/process-route-tab/`

Other possibly relevant info I can think of is:

- I am using Areas
- This is the only route mapped

The mapping below works fine for this URL: `http://localhost/Manufacture/Job/View/1234/`

But including the tab part as in the example URL above gets a 'The resource cannot be found' error.

### Global.asax.cs excerpt

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{tab}/", // URL with parameters
        new { 
           controller = "Account", 
           action = "Index", 
           id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
           tab = UrlParameter.Optional
        }, // Parameter defaults
        new string[] { "Test.WebApp.Controllers" }
   );
}
```

### JobController.cs excerpt

```
public class JobController : BaseController 
{

    // ...

    public ActionResult View(int id, string tab = "info", string notifications = "")
    {
        // Never gets here!
        Notification.UnSerialize(notifications);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Among various tinkering that has made no difference, I have so far tried:

- Removing the `notifications` parameter from the action method
- hard coding controller name and action name in the mapping i.e. `job/view/{id}/{tab}`
- having this as a separate mapping that preceded the default mapping, in the `RegisterRoutes` method

Hopefully someone can shed some light here, and stop me haemorrhaging time on such a small detail.

Comment: if you are using areas, this should not be the only route. you should change the route in the `ManufactureAreaRegistration.cs` in the `Manufacture` area folder.

Comment: Thanks @shakib - you're absolutely right. I didn't realise there were routes set up in each of the area registration files.  I've updated it there and it then worked as expected.

Comment: you are welcome. added as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each area has a area route registration file in the area folder. You should change the route in the `ManufactureAreaRegistration.cs` file in the `Manufacture` area folder.

something like,

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Manufacture_default",
        "Manufacture/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{tab}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, tab = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Regards